# Predicate builder Convert.ToInt32 giving error?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, predicatebuilder

In asp.net mvc4 project I am using predicate builder. Here is my code:

```
public static Expression<Func<AdModel, bool>> AddConditionToQuery( )
{
    Guid g = new Guid("d521291f-2edb-4efc-96ac-25a4993bf028");
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => (p.OptionID == g) && ( Convert.ToInt32(p.AdDetail) > 10000) );
    return predicate;
}


var result = (
           from p in mev.AdModels.AsExpandable().Where(filter)
           select new
           {
               mev.AdCategoryTrees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.AdID == p.AdID).CategoryID,
               mev.AdCategoryTrees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.AdID == p.AdID).CategoryName,
           }).Distinct();
```

For `Convert.ToInt32` I am taking error below. Is there any other wat to do thıs.

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the type of `p.AdDetail`?

Comment: type of p.AdDetail is string.

Comment: [Quite a common problem](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method+'Int32+ToInt32(System.String)').

Comment: Why do you store numerical data as `string`/`varchar`?

Comment: Because in AdDetail I have to keep both string and integer values.

Comment: And this code runs without errors in LinqPad.